# Exception when getting the Zone Rules of a Java TimeZone?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I've been having an issue getting the `ZoneRules` for a timezone in Java. I have a `TimeZone` and I am trying to the `ZoneRules` using this code:

```
TimeZone tz = getTimeZone();
ZoneRules rules = ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(tz.toZoneId().getId(), true);
```

When the timezone is regional (like `"Asia/Dubai"` for example), it works correctly. But when it is an offset like `"GMT-07:00"`, it throws an exception:

```
"ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: GMT-07:00".
```

I printed all the output of `ZoneRulesProvider.getAvailableZoneIds()` and it seems there is no zone like `"GMT-07:00"` but there is a zone `"Etc/GMT-7"`.

Could anyone please explain why the `toZoneId` method of the `TimeZone` class returns an invalid `ZoneId`? What is the correct way to convert a `TimeZone` to a valid `ZoneId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show how you create the TimeZone in the getTimeZone() method. TimeZone has a list of supported ids which can be retrieved as follows

```
    for (String zoneId : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
        System.out.println(zoneId);
    }
```

You will see, that it doesn't show GMT-07:00, but only "Etc/GMT-7" (amongst others). It seems that your code is doing

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-07:00");
```

which creates a TimeZone with a custom id. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRulesProvider.html mentions the following:

> Rules are looked up primarily by zone ID, as used by ZoneId. Only zone region IDs may be used, zone offset IDs are not used here.

To get the official timeZone, try the following code

```
    TimeZone customTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-07:00");
    TimeZone officialTimeZone = null;
    for (String timeZoneId : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
        if (TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId).hasSameRules(customTimeZone)){
            officialTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId);
            break;
        }
    }
    ZoneRules zoneRules = ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(officialTimeZone.toZoneId().getId(), true);
    System.out.println(zoneRules);
```

Or alternatively

```
    TimeZone officialTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-07:00").getRawOffset())[0]);
    ZoneRules zoneRules =ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(officialTimeZone.toZoneId().getId(), true);
    System.out.println(zoneRules);
```

Comment: Thank you Guenther. I never thought to check the available timezone IDs so I didn't know that GMT -07:00 was a custom ID timezone. This is also explained in the documentation for the TimeZone class so it is my fault for not reading it. Anyways, your code works great. Thanks again.